# static int is getting more count than AtomicInteger in single thread, why so?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Output of the following code is `9123:9158`

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class StackOverflow {

    private static AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static int staticInt = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int atomicInt = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();

        staticInt++;

        try {
            // recursive call to main() to get StackOverflowError
            main(args);

        } catch(StackOverflowError soe) {

            System.out.println(atomicInt+":"+staticInt);
            // staticInt gets more count, why so?
        }
    }
}
```

This produces a difference of 35 between `static int` and `AtomicInteger`. I am not sure why this behaves so and I have these questions I would like to get answers for.

While running on a single thread both should give same count right? Any idea why this is not behaving so?

How do we get the correct number of calls required for `StackOverflowError` to occur?

Is it wrong to use `AtomicInteger` in a `static` contekt?

Comment: try using `System.out.println(atomicInt.get()+":"+staticInt);`

Comment: atomicInt is int result of atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();

Comment: @WarFox It's a result of `incrementAndGet` from a different stack frame.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you are printing `atomicInt`. If you printed `atomicInteger` instead you would get the expected result.

There is one `atomicInt` variable per call to `main`, so in your example there are 9000+ such variables.

When you get the StackOverflowError, the execution goes through the stack in reverse order until the `System.out.println` statement can execute (it may throw a SOE too!), and the value of the `atomicInt` corresponding to that specific `main` invocation is smaller than the curent value of `staticInt` or `atomicInteger`.

In other words, in your example, 34 StackoverflowError are thrown and the 35th invocation of `System.out.println` succeeds, but `atomicInt` in that invocation of `main` is 35 less than the current value of `staticInt`, hence 9123 vs 9158.

To see it you can modify your program like so:

```
private static int soeCount = 0;

//...

} catch (StackOverflowError soe) {
    soeCount++;
    System.out.println(atomicInt + ":" + staticInt + " -> " + soeCount);
    // staticInt gets more count, why so?
}
```

and you should see that `soeCount` is larger than 1 (although not necessarily equal to the difference as `soeCount++` may not be executed on each stack frame.

Comment: cool.. thanks much for this explanation. If I print              System.out.println(atomicInteger.get()+":"+staticInt); we get right count which is 9158.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `System.out.println(atomicInt+":"+staticInt);` is also causing a stack overflow. So you actually print the values of a few incarnations earlier.

`staticInt` is a static field, so it has the max number of incarnations, while `atomicInt` is a local variable in the incarnation of `main` that actually succeeds in executing the `println`.